# Split row into multiple rows in SQL Server for insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a SQL query that will insert a single row as 2 rows in another table.

My data looks like this:

```
size | indemnity_factor | monitoring_factor
--------------------------------------------    
0    | 1.00             | 1.5
```

The end data looks like this:

```
id | claim_component_type_code | size | adjustment_factor | valid_from_date
------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
1  | Indemnity                 | 0    | 2.5000000         | 2014-01-01
1  | Monitoring                | 1    | 1.5000000         | 2014-01-01
```

I want to add an entry of Indemnity and Monitoring for every row in the first data source. I haven't really got an idea how to go about it, would be very appreciative if someone could help. Sorry for the rough data but I can't post images with my reputation apparently.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain how you get from table 1 to table 2? I'm lost

Comment: So am I. Why is adjustment_factor = 2.5 in the first row? Why is size = 1 in the second row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`unpivot`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
select * from 
(select size, indemnity_factor as indemnity, monitoring_factor as monitoring 
     from yourtable) src
unpivot (adjustment_factor for claim_component_type_code in (indemnity, monitoring) ) u
```